# How to handle different xmpp priorities from the same user

Tags: algorithm, xmpp, google-talk

I want to determine whether a Google Talk (aka gchat) contact is away, available, dnd, or unavailable (I think those are the only types of availabilities on gchat).

So far I have been using sleekxmpp to interact with gchat and read the xml etc... The issue is that quite frequently a contact is signed in on multiple resources with the same account (e.g. a phone and a computer), each with its own priority and availability. So I want to determine who is "top dawg", what I mean by that is, which of their signed on resources should I use to determine their availability.

I am thinking this has a lot to do with priority levels, but I am not exactly sure how, from what I can tell two resources can have the same priority level and different availabilities.

I realize there is not going to be a perfect solution to finding their "true" availability, but I figure Google makes a decision about what color to show the availability icon next to a contact based on whatever algorithm, so I can try to figure this out too.

Answer (score 2):

This is really up to you, there is no standard answer for it (generally protocol specifications try to steer clear of dictating user interface design).

You can either display each connection individually in the interface, or try and be clever and merge them. How you ultimately merge them is up to you, but contrary to Robin's answer (which is factually correct) I *do* recommend using priority because it reflects the status of the actual resource that will be the recipient of any messages the user sends to that contact.

For example if the contact has one resource 'dnd' with priority of 5, and another resource is 'away' with a priority of 0, it makes sense to display 'dnd', even though 'away' is the more "available" state. This is because when you send a message to the contact's bare JID, they will receive it to the 'dnd' resource.

In the case of a priority tie (two resources with the same priority) you have yet another choice to make. I suggest attaching weights to each possible status and showing the "most available". I would order them this way for example:

1. chat | dnd
2. (none - standard 'available')
3. away
4. xa

This still leaves the edge case of 'chat' and 'dnd'. They are both strong (but conflicting) statements about a user's availability (ie. "talk to me!" and "go away!") and therefore should probably take priority over others.

Really if the contact has two resources with the same priority at both 'dnd' and 'chat' then there isn't that much more you can do, except perhaps let the last received presence take priority - as that will usually indicate the resource they were most recently active at.

Comment: thank you for this well thought out answer! I especially like your point in the last paragraph about the last received presence taking priority. I am still curious how Google does it.

Comment: Google actually invented their own semi-hacky solution. They have an extension that allows clients to control a "master" status: https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/shared_status - I was going to mention it in my answer but didn't, as no other servers support it. At least one open-source client does though, Telepathy/Empathy.

Answer (score 1):

Well, wouldn't they only be deemed unavailable if all connections where showing as not available.  If any connection they have shows them as available, then they are available in some capacity.  Priority has no bearing on availability.

Priority levels come into play for the server to route messages when the message is destined to the bare JID (no particular connection).  If a user has multiple connections, the server will deliver the message to the one with the highest priority.  Multiple connections with the same priority can behave differently, depending on the server and its configuration.  I believe Google, for example, will deliver to all resources, whereas Openfire (by default) will only deliver to one of them, based on an internal algorithm.  Both of these behaviours are valid according to the spec.

Comment: I am trying to determine, specifically away (yellow), dnd (red), avail (green), or unavail (gray). Not just avail/unavail. I agree that a user is unavailable if they are not avail/dnd/away, but what if one of their sessions is away and one is available, what are they considered?